# Clojure Hello World - "No such namespace" error

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen, swank-clojure

I'm trying to write a helloworld with clojure. I'm using leinengen with emacs and swank-clojure.

Here's what my `src/hello.clj` contains:

```
(ns hello)

(defn hello []  
(println "Hello World"))
```

When I `clojure-jack-in` and `C-c C-c` over the function, I get:

```
No such namespace: hello                                                   
[Thrown class java.lang.Exception]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `C-c C-c`, you're asking the backend to compile the function at point within the "hello" namespace, but that namespace doesn't yet exists -- you haven't executed the `(ns hello)` line yet. So try `C-c C-k` instead, which will compile the entire file. Thereafter, `C-c C-c` will allow you to re-compile the function.

Comment: Wow. I spent a whole hour trying to figure this out!